# Which is the best way to write a XML Document to a file in java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, transformation, xerces

I am trying to write an XML file. I was able to create the Document using the following code. I want to write this Document to a file with indent support. Currently my code looks like this.

Which is a better technology to parse XMl and write to a file.

```
public void writeXmlToFile(Document dom) throws IOException {
    OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(dom);
    format.setIndenting(true);

    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer ( new FileOutputStream(
                                 new File("sample.xml")), format);
    serializer.serialize(dom);
}
```

or is using transformer a better approach.

```
public void writeXMLToFile(DOcument dom) throws TransformerException, IOException {
    TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer        trans = transFact.newTransformer();

    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    trans.setOutputProeprty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

    StreamResult resut  = new StreamResult(new FileWriter(output));
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDOC);

    trans.transform(source, result);
    writer.close();    
}
```

What is the difference between the two approaches? And which of these techniques provide better performance?

Comment: Assuming that by "better performance" you mean "uses less CPU time", why don't you write a loop that writes the file, say, 100000 times with each method and calculates the time spent?

Comment: which XMLSerializer are you using?  what package does it belong to?

Comment: I am using the xerces parser - "com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer"

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I would suggest a third way which is the W3C proposed DOM Load and Save API. The code is self-explaining.

```
DOMImplementationLS ls = (DOMImplementationLS)
    DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance().getDOMImplementation("LS");

// Gets a basic document from string.
LSInput input = ls.createLSInput();
String xml = "<bookstore city='shanghai'><a></a><b/></bookstore>";
InputStream istream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
input.setByteStream(istream);
LSParser parser = ls.createLSParser(DOMImplementationLS.MODE_SYNCHRONOUS, null);
Document document = parser.parse(input);

// Creates a LSSerializer object and saves to file.
LSSerializer serializer = ls.createLSSerializer();
serializer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", true);
LSOutput output = ls.createLSOutput();
OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\foo.xml");
output.setByteStream(ostream);        
serializer.write(document, output);
```

Unlike XmlSerializer which is more or less a pre-standard, this approach is preferred as it is supported by all compliant implementations. The performance largely depends on vendor implementation though.